# Counting distance takes too long

Tags: r, for-loop, geosphere

i have a data frame with more than 10 million rows. 
I want to count the distance between the lat-lon pairs, and add them to a nem column.
I have tried to run the script(see below) , but it takes too long(more than 5 hours).
Any tip how can i boost the speed of this process? I use the geosphere package to count distance between the lat-lon pairs.

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(dm_kekk)))
{
dm_kekk$dist[i]<-distm (c(dm_kekk$lon[i], dm_kekk$lat[i]), 
                         c(dm_kekk$lon_ok[i], dm_kekk$lat_ok[i]), 
                         fun = distHaversine)

}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Always give some example of your data and the output you expect to make answering the question a bit easier. 
One option is for you to just parallel the process or try with `dplyr` mutate.

```
library(doParallel)
cores <- detectCores() -1
cl <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

oper_dist <- foreach(i=1:seq_len(nrow(dm_kekk))) %dopar% {
library(geosphere)
  distm (c(dm_kekk$lon[i], dm_kekk$lat[i]), 
                     c(dm_kekk$lon_ok[i], dm_kekk$lat_ok[i]), 
                     fun = distHaversine)
}
stopCluster(cl)
dm_kekk$dist <- do.call(c, oper_dist)
```

Or use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

dm_kekk %>% mutate(dist = distm(lon, lat, lon_ok, lat_ok, fun = distHaversine))
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. The dplyr way gives an error, so the right code looks like :  `mutate(dist = distm (cbind(lon, lat), cbind(lon_ok, lat_ok), fun = distHaversine))`.

Comment: HI @deaux, could you please mark the question as correct if the solution worked? Also, did you do benchmarking to find out which of the solution were optimal?

Comment: hi @ Hanjo Jo'burg Odendaal! The dplyr way is much faster then the parallel way. But the syntax of distm was incorrect. The right code looks like: `mutate(dist = distm (cbind(lon, lat), cbind(lon_ok, lat_ok), fun = distHaversine))`.